# Optimized way for data filtering and calculation

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, datastore

Given that -

```
A = fn (B, C, D)
```

Where `fn` could be any function which may contain simple and complex calculations.

My need is to calculate the possible values of A, B, C, D at run time based on their current value (if available)

Lets take an example to understand it better. Suppose -

```
A = B + C * D
```

Now, if `B=2`, `C=3` and `D=5` then `A = 17`

if `B=1 to 2`, `C=1 to 5` and `D=5`, then `A = 6 to 27`

if `A=10 to 20`, `B=100`, `D=1 to 10`, then `A = 110 to 1020`

Similarly based on possible values of B, C and D we can calculate possible values of `A`.

Now my need to do the same for `B`, `C` and `D` also i.e. if I know values of `A`, `C` and `D` then I should be able to tell the possible value of `B` - (by keeping in mind that there is not way to directly know what is `B = fn2 (A, C, D)` and also `fn` may not be just mathematical calculations.

One way I know is to pre calculate the data in database for all possible values and then filter it out based on the available values (assuming storage is not a problem).

What are other possible ways to achieve this with minimum response time?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, what you want to do is to find maximum and minimum of `fn`, that is, to solve [constraint optimization problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constrained_optimization): first you look for a minimum of `fn` given constraints (ranges for B, C and D), then you minimize `-fn` at the same domain.

Luckily, you have only 3 variables, so this should not be a problem. But the speed of an algorithm depends on how much information of a function you have. Ideally, you should be able to calculate the [Hessian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix), though knowing just [gradient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient) would suffice. Finally, if you don't know the gradient, you still can approximate it using [finite differences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference#Finite_difference_in_several_variables).

If you don't know optimized function in advance, but know it's symbolic representation (formula) in terms of basic operations (like `+`, `-`, *etc* and elementary functions like `exp`, `log`, *etc*), you can do [symbolic differentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_computation) to obtain a formula for the gradient (and the hessian).

I'm not a specialist when it comes to optimization, but I think projected methods (like projected gradient descent, projected Newton method) will work. Also, interior point method may be useful, but I'm not familiar with it.

Assumptions have been made:

1. Your function is continuous.
2. Moreover, your function is "sane". There are instances of functions with weird geometry that are quite hard to optimize.
3. Your function is of real arguments. If that's not the case, most likely, for "sane" function, optimum will be somewhere in 4 int-valued neighbors of that point. Though, that's not guaranteed.